# How to test an UpdateView in Django?

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-testing

I'm trying to test a view (UpdateView) in Django but this doesn't work. Is a view that is used to edit user first name and last name (basic).

This is the view:

```
class UserProfileEditView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'user/edit.html'
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    def get_success_url(self):
        redirect_to = self.request.GET.get(
            'next',
            reverse('main:user_detail', args=[self.request.user.pk])
        )
        return redirect_to
```

In the `urls.py` file I have this path:

```
path(
    'user/<pk>/edit/',
    views.UserProfileEditView.as_view(),
    name='user_edit'
),
```

And lastly here is the test I've written where I would only like to test that a user can change his first name to blank but this doesn't work:

```
class TestModel(TestCase):
    def test_blank_first_name(self):
        user = factories.UserFactory()
        post_data = {
            'first_name': '',
            'last_name': user.last_name
        }
        response = self.client.post(
            reverse('main:user_edit', kwargs={'pk': user.pk}),
            post_data
        )
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
        user.refresh_from_db()
        self.assertEqual(user.first_name, '')
```

This is the error when I run `python manage.py test`:

```
AssertionError: 'laugh' != ''
```

It mean that the first_name didn't change from 'laugh' to '' like was expected.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: try `' '` instead of `''`

Comment: it doesn't work neither

Answer (score 0):

Román, I hope you are doing great!
Why are you trying to update a user using a post? Why would you not use patch?
Also, why you are expecting a 302 Redirect instead of a 200 OK?

To update, you will need to use patch [or put if you are providing every field required for the user]. This would be importing `from rest_framework import status`

```
response = self.client.patch(
    reverse('main:user_edit', kwargs={'pk': user.pk}),
    post_data
)
self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
user.refresh_from_db()
self.assertEqual(user.first_name, '')
```

Hope this works for you :)

Comment: This isn't about REST Framework, it's about regular Django views and forms, which accept data as POST, and upon success do a redirect with 302.